# Cocoa - changing the provisioning will change the appid?

Tags: ios, cocoa

In my app i store some data in the device storage. This data is stored in the application support directory.
The path of the directory, as i saw, include my Application Id.

Can the Application Id change?

Is it possible that changing the provisioning (when the old provisioning will expire, and i would like to load a new version the application) will change the Application Id?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The application ID is connected to the ID you registered on the provisioning portal. The certificates expire, but the IDs do not. You can easily create a new certificate with the same ID.

Comment: So there is no way that uploading a new version of my application will change the application ID?

Comment: That is correct - the moment you try to upload the same application but with a different ID, iTunes Connect will complain. :-)

Comment: what about [NSUserDefaults standartUserDefaults] ? can this data be deleted?

Comment: Still tied to your application ID